# Sorting Counter by year in Python

Tags: python, counter

The code below counts the amounts of occurrences of individual years in a row of a CSV file.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

out=open("meteors.csv", "r")
data=csv.reader(out)
data.next()
data=[row for row in data]
out.close()

year = [] 

for row in data:
    if row[2]=='':
        continue
    else:       
        year.append(row[2])

c = Counter(year)

print c
```

The results come out like this:

```
Counter ({'2012':15, '2004':10, '2008':4})
```

Can anyone give me a piece of code I can add in order to sort the results by year?

Comment: @abc: no, this is an attempt to sort the dictionary by *key*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
sorted(c.items(),key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Comment: any reason??? for downvote???

Comment: 1) It's wrong. 2) Did you visit any of 2 links under **This question already has an answer here:**?

Comment: how can u say its wrong???

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid. I inserted in just above 'print c'

Comment: u need to try `print sorted(c.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])`

Comment: @abc correct me where i am wrong, i thing u talking about reverse=True argument???

Comment: @Richie is that worked for u??

Comment: @Hackaholic This has ordered the data in order of the value rather than the key, however I managed to get some different code from the link provided by abc which sorted it for me. Thanks

Comment: so yeah its wrong bcos u sort by second element not by first

Comment: @ab ahh i dident noticed need to sort on 1st, let me edit

Comment: @Richie yea in place of x[1] put x[0], check the edit, i thought u want on values, sorry fro my bad

Comment: @Hackaholic Yep works now. Thanks!